# I have a listview with checkboxes and i filter the listview values and checked a values after filtering checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a listview with checkboxes and I filter the listview values and checked a values after filtering checkbox checking positions will be change. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Use a arraylist which hold checked item position.than on getView(,,,) method of adapter check those value in arraylist and uncheck other(not in arraylist). Or create an Handler class which contain checkbox and check position after filtering and notify if process complete

Comment: Thanks for your replay @RajeshTiwari